# How to make `dpkg -l` display all packages instead of only packages having "ii" state

Tags: debian, apt

I use `dpkg -l` to list installed packages on my Ubuntu system

It only displays packages in state "ii", except if I explicitly query a package:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version      Architecture Description
+++-=====================-============-============-=================================
un  linux-headers-686-pae <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

How can I make `dpkg -l` display all packages, i.e. any package known to the system (not just installed ones)?

Extra: Can this information be obtained using `apt-get` or similar commands (not `apt list`)?

Answer (score 6):

When `dpkg -l` isn’t given a pattern, it ignores packages marked as “not-installed”. To work around that, give it a pattern:

```
dpkg -l '*'
```

`apt list` is `apt`-specific, similar to `dpkg-query` (which handles `dpkg -l`), and doesn’t have an `apt-get` or `apt-cache` equivalent.

Comment: I though that `apt` was a front-end for `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc., so that whatever can be done with `apt` can be done with one of `apt-*` - isn't that true? What I mean is that `apt-*` came first, and then `apt` was invented, because people thought `apt-*` were too difficult to comprehend?

Comment: `apt` adds some of its own specific features; see `man apt` for details.